# Mypy method definition is incompatible with definition in base class

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

I have a parent class that does something and two child classes that wrap a method in orthogonal ways.  When I try to combine the two child classes, mypy complains with the following error.

> Definition of "run" in base class "Foo" is incompatible with
>   definition in base class "Bar"

How are the two classes "incompatible" and how do I modify my code to appease mypy?  Can I do it without making

```
class Parent:
    def run(self, a, b):
        pass


class Foo(Parent):
    def run(self, a, b, foo=None, **kwargs):
        print('foo', foo)
        super().run(a, b, **kwargs)


class Bar(Parent):
    def run(self, a, b, bar=None, **kwargs):
        print('bar', bar)
        super().run(a, b, **kwargs)


class C(Foo, Bar):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Mypy complains only because you are trying to inherit C from Foo and Bar, which have the same method run, but with different arguments.
To make Mypy happy you have to either make your run functions in Foo and Bar classes the same (match same function signature), or do not inherit class C from both of them.

Comment: That's actually incorrect. `C` inherits both `Foo` and `Bar`, not the other way around. Also, you can use `@typing.overload` to overload the method in `C`. There are more options than you specify.

Answer (score 0):

One simple fix is to make `foo` and `bar` keyword-only arguments:

```
class Parent:
    def run(self, a, b):
        pass


class Foo(Parent):
    def run(self, a, b, *, foo=None, **kwargs):
        print('foo', foo)
        super().run(a, b,  **kwargs)


class Bar(Parent):
    def run(self, a, b, *, bar=None, **kwargs):
        print('bar', bar)
        super().run(a, b, **kwargs)


class C(Foo, Bar):
    pass
```

The problem with using positional arguments is that `mypy` can't tell, if you were to make a call like `C().run(1,2,3)`, what each call should do with `3`.  Think of `C` as a `Foo`, it should be the value of `foo`. But thinking of `C` as a `Bar`, it should be the value of `bar`. Generally, it's a bad idea to add *positional* arguments to the signature of an overriden method, even if at runtime `3` will be bound to the first available parameter of whichever method is called first.

Also, because there's no way to pass positional arguments for both `foo` and `bar` with an instance of `C`, you would have to pass them as keyword arguments anyway, so you may as well declare them as such.

Comment: Actually, now with Python >=3.8, you can use `/` to specify positional-only arguments. See [PEP 570](https://peps.python.org/pep-0570/).

Comment: Using positional-only parameters doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: No, of course not. I wasn't trying to suggest that solves the problem. I was just mentioning it to you. `foo` and `bar` are _standard arguments_ in the OP example, not positional or keyword. They can be _either_ positional or keyword. The OP has simply given both a default value of `None`.

Comment: Actually, I take back what I said. You are in fact incorrect, unfortunately. You can solve the problem with `/` or `*`, but more importantly it has less to do with the name of the third argument than with keyword collisions. I will explain in my answer.

Comment: You are missing my point: with positional arguments, you have to explicitly define `C.__init__`, imposing an arbitrary ordering on the "inherited" parameters. With keyword arguments, you don't have to define `C.__init__` *at all*. Your answer doesn't address multiple inheritance at all, nor does it mention positional-only parameters (so I *still* don't know why you think their existence is relevant to the problem at hand.)

Comment: There is also no such thing as "standard" arguments: arguments are either positional (which can be used to assign values to positional-only or regular *parameters*, from left to right) or keyword (which can be used to assign values to positional parameters which *didn't* get assigned with positional arguments and keyword-only parameters).

Comment: (That is, there is a *two*-way distinction between arguments and a *three*-way distinction among parameters.)

Comment: None of your follow up comments are correct. Please reread my answer carefully. Standard arguments are referenced in PEPs, python docs, and tutorials. My answer is fully backed up with reproducible results on mypy playground. The things you claim I didn't do, I very much did. Your solution works, but your answer is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

This may actually be a `mypy` bug. Nothing is statically typed in your code, so `mypy` should read the types of all arguments as `Any` and not report any errors.

In fact, if you use `pyright`, you will get no errors with this code: see [the `pyright` playground code](https://pyright-playground.decorator-factory.su/?issue=microsoft/pyright/2662)

**NB**: *There are several different static type checkers for python*:

- [`mypy`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html): The original (python core dev) static type checker
- [`pyright`](https://github.com/Microsoft/pyright): Microsoft's static type checker
- [`pyre`](https://pyre-check.org/): Facebook's static type checker
- [`pytype`](https://github.com/google/pytype): Google's static type checker

and for enforcement of runtime type checking:

- [`pydantic`](https://pypi.org/project/pydantic/)

---

> How are the two classes "incompatible"?

As `@chepner` correctly surmised, the issue is due to the conflict over positional versus keyword arguments, but his/her answer is not fully correct.

The reason they are incompatible is because they open the potential for a **keyword collision** in one method, but not the other. This is a kind of [Liskov Violation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

##### Answer

Python [distinguishes between parameters vs. arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#faq-argument-vs-parameter). Your function *parameters* are [***positional-or-keyword***](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-parameter), meaning you can use them **either by position or by keyword**. (Sometimes authors have loosely used the term *standard arguments* when referring to arguments passed to *positional-or-keyword* parameters (like [this realpython.com article](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/#ordering-arguments-in-a-function)), but that's not a term defined by python in their [glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html).

I will use the [mypy playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10) to support my claims.

If you remove `**kwargs` from the `run` functions, you will actually not get any errors:

- [No `**kwargs` in `run()` methods](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8&gist=103fe953e90ce3b1f7bd09ef3a3c6297)

This doesn't fail because, due to the MRO of cooperative multiple inheritance, `C` calls `Foo` first and `Foo` calls `Bar` because you use `super`. You can't even call `c.run()` with `bar` because it doesn't have it:

```py
>>> c.run(1, 2, bar='baz')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 27, in <module>
    c.run(1, 2, bar='baz')
TypeError: run() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bar'
```

This is all deterministic, so there's no potential for ambiguity here.

The problem occurs when you add `**kwargs`. Because of it, you can get one function to work, but not the other.

In every case, whenever you use `**kwargs`, you run the risk of accidentally passing a keyword argument that has the same name as an existing argument in your function. For example, if we bring back the `**kwargs`

```py
...

class Foo(Parent):
    def run(self, a, b, foo, **kwargs):
        print('foo', foo)
        super().run(a, b, **kwargs)

...
```

and call `c` like so, we get an error:

```py
>>> c.run(1, 2, 3, foo='baz')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 27, in <module>
    c.run(1, 2, 3, foo='baz')
TypeError: run() got multiple values for argument 'foo'
```

Because your arguments are standard, `foo` can be either positional or keyword, so we confuse `run()` here with what we are doing.

If we consider the case of `Bar` with `**kwargs` added back:

```py
class Bar(Parent):
    def run(self, a, b, bar, **kwargs):
        print('bar', bar)
        super().run(a, b, **kwargs)
```

We can call `Bar.run()` with a keyword argument of `foo` because `foo` is not in the parameter list of `Bar.run()`:

```py
>>> b = Bar()
>>> b.run(1, 2, 3, foo='baz')
bar 3
```

Hence, there is an incompatibility because you can call `Bar` one way, but not `Foo` with the same arguments (and vice-versa if we were to pass `bar` as a keyword argument).

There are two ways you can overcome this error. The first, shown by `@chepner`, will work if you want `foo` and `bar` to be keyword-only.

The second way is if you want to specify `foo` and `bar` to be positional only.  Below are links to mypy playground with working examples:

- [In Python >=3.8, you can use `/`](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8&gist=8f6e2053213ebbe594e9cc1ae0889c6a)
- [In Python <3.8, you can prepend positional arg names with `__`](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.7&gist=360aab9ded3ab684136d8ec1603b596c)